# Tell vim to treat character as full width

Tags: options, unicode, font

I am wondering if it is possible to tell vim to treat an individial code point in the unicode plain. I am aware of the ambiwidth option, but it does not help with my current task because the relevant characters are in the upper unicode plane, eg. `\mathcal` characters.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve? This could help us give you a relevant answer.

Comment: I'm using a plugin that conceals `mathcal` with unicode math characters, and the character gets cutoff halfway.

Comment: @MaxXiong welcome to [vi.se]! Please [edit] the question to add the detail about `mathcal`? If you can give a full reproducer, that would help someone give you a great answer... Please also specify whether you're using Vim in a terminal or a GUI version of Vim (which?) and which fonts you're using...